# Why the first-order derivative is missing when composing a Hamiltonian of simple harmonic oscillator by the lowering and the raising operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, differentiation, hamiltonian

Given the lowering operator ($a$) and the raising operator ($a^\dagger$)

$$\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m \hbar \omega}}\left(-i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i m \omega x\right) \\
a^\dagger &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m \hbar \omega}}\left(-i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i m \omega x\right),
\end{align*}$$

it claims the Hamiltonian of a one-dimension simple harmonic oscillator can be composed by

$$\begin{align*}
H &= \hbar \omega \left( a^\dagger a + \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
&= - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2
\end{align*}$$

Below are the steps.

$$\begin{align*}
\hbar \omega \left( a^\dagger a + \frac{1}{2} \right)
&= \hbar \omega \left[
  \frac{1}{2m \hbar \omega}
  \left( -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i m \omega x \right)
  \left( -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i m \omega x \right)
  + \frac{1}{2} \right] \\
&= \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} 
  + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2 
  + \frac{1}{2} \omega x \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
&= H
  + \frac{1}{2} \omega x \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\end{align*}$$

Why I left

$$
\frac{1}{2} \omega x \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$

at the end? How to cancel it?

**Note:** I removed most of the equations I posted originally because the equations make others feel this question disobeys the policies. If you hit the same problem as me, check the removed equations in the edit histories.

Comment: I didn't go through your steps, but I strongly recommend applying the operators to a *test function* $f(x)$ when doing the algebra. It is incredibly easy to make mistakes if you work directly with operators that you would not make when using a test function. In other words: include a function $f(x)$ at the right hand side of your first equation, and work out all the derivatives, etc, by applying them to $f(x)$. At the end you should have "something" times $f(x)$; the "something" is your operator result.

Comment: The term you haven’t handled correctly is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x f(x)$.

Comment: Please remove the last para. We don't need the argument whether the question needs to be closed or left open. Questions should contain only the query and the effort. Meta text should be discussed in meta.

Comment: As per the recommendation from an editor, I moved the argument about the homework-like marking to comment.

Comment: This is not my homework. I know, in Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions, someone said we don't know of OP's statement about their effort or situation in the real world. Yeah. But why assume I am a "lazy person" instead of a "learner without many resources"? You didn't know me at all, but you assume me in a bad way. Before I posted the question, I thought there is a physical reason to remove the term. I didn't know it is caused by a wrong calculation.

Comment: You think it's a calculation problem is because you already know the problem is a calculation problem. I didn't. Please do not punish me by marking the question as homework. This is not a good culture for the community.

Comment: *I thought there is a physical reason to remove the term.* That was an unreasonable assumption. It is *very* unusual for terms to simply be “removed” in a physics calculation; math is math, and you don’t normally just get rid of problematic terms in a calculation. The 99.9999% likely explanation was that you had simply made a mistake. We *all* make mistakes. But this site isn’t about correcting mistakes in calculations.

Comment: You cannot evade the no-check-my-work policy simply by claiming that you assumed you hadn’t made a mistake and thought that there was some physics going on instead. Therefore I have downvoted since I cannot vote to close.

Comment: I also upvoted one of your other questions that I felt was appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that
$$
\partial_x x = 1+ x\partial_x.
$$
You forgot the $x\partial_x$ when passing from the first line of your calculation to the second.